# A question about mdframed

Tags: mdframed

Recently i found an mdframed based environment and i use it for typesetting my examples .... the problem is that the program inserts pagebreaks and there are large gaps inside the text of the example .. it is not possible to reproduce exactly the situation .. however in the next MWE there are two blank pages and maybe the reason for which they appear is the same ... note that in the past i used mdframed withount any problem, maybe the problem is associated with the way the mdframed is used in this case .. the output text is in Greek, just ignote it .. thanks a lot !!

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[american,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[usetwoside,framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}    

\usepackage[a4paper,
        inner=1.55cm,
        outer=1.55cm,
        left=1.55cm,
        right=1.55cm,
        top=1.58cm,
        bottom=1.58cm,
        headsep=4mm]{geometry} 


\def\blackink{\special{color cmyk 0 0 0 1.}}
\def\whiteink{\special{color cmyk 0 0 0 0}}               

\newcounter{example2}[chapter]
\def\theexample2{\thechapter-\arabic{example2}\blackink}
\newenvironment{example2}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{example2}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue] % blue!20
{\strut \whiteink ΠΑΡΑΔΕΙΓΜΑ~\theexample2\blackink};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue] %blue!20
{\strut \whiteink \textbf {ΠΑΡΑΔΕΙΓΜ}~\theexample2:~\whiteink#1\blackink};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=3pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=black!10]\relax%
\label{#2}
}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}                

\begin{example2}[Παράδειγμα]{}

Σε αυτό το παράδειγμα αποδεικνύουμε ορισμένες από τις ιδιότητες του Πίνακα 4.1 έτσι ώστε να εξοικειωθούμε με τον τρόπο χειρισμού αυτών των σημαντικών ιδιοτήτων και ταυτόχρονα να θεμελιώσουμε μία βάση για την επίλυση κάποιων από τα προβλήματα που περιλαμβάνονται στο τέλος του κεφαλαίου. Θα αποδείξουμε μόνο τις ιδιότητες του αριστερού μέλους έχοντας στη διάθεσή μας εκείνες του δεξιού μέλους, ενώ το αντίστροφο αποδεικνύεται με ένα τρόπο παρόμοιο με τις αποδείξεις που θα παραθέσουμε εδώ.

Θεωρείστε για παράδειγμα την Ιδιότητα 3, η οποία διαβάζεται ως εξής: εάν $f(x,y)$ είναι μία πραγματική συνάρτηση, τότε το πραγματικό μέρος του μετασχηματισμού της κατά \textlatin{Fourier} είναι άρτιο, ενώ το φανταστικό της μέλος είναι περιττό. Με εντελώς ανάλογο τρόπο, εάν ένας μετασχηματισμός \textlatin{Fourier} έχει πραγματικό και φανταστικό μέρος που είναι άρτια και περιττά αντίστοιχα, τότε, ο αντίστροφος μετασχηματισμός είναι μία πραγματική συνάρτηση. Αυτή η ιδιότητα αποδεικνύεται με τον ακόλουθο τρόπο: Στη γενική περίπτωση, η συνάρτηση $F(u,\upsilon)$ είναι μιγαδική και επομένως μπορεί να εκφραστεί ως το άθροισμα ενός πραγματικού και ενός φανταστικού μέρους, έτσι ώστε να γράψουμε $F(u,\upsilon)=R(u,\upsilon)+jΙ(u,\upsilon)$. Κατά συνέπειαν θα είναι $F^*(u,\upsilon)=R(u,\upsilon)-jI(u,\upsilon)$. Επίσης θα έχουμε $F(-u,-\upsilon)=R(-u,-\upsilon)+jI(-u,-\upsilon)$. Ωστόσο, όπως αποδείξαμε παραπάνω, εάν η συνάρτηση $f(x,y)$ είναι πραγματική, τότε θα είναι $F^*(u,\upsilon)=F(-u,-\upsilon)$ το οποίο, σύμφωνα με τις τελευταίες δύο εξισώσεις, σημαίνει πως $R(u,\upsilon)=R(-u,-\upsilon)$ και $I(u,\upsilon)=-I(-u,-\upsilon)$. Επομένως, σύμφωνα με τις Εξισώσεις (4.6-11α) και (4.6-11β), οι συναρτήσεις $R$ και $I$ θα χαρακτηρίζονται από άρτια και περιττή συμμετρία αντίστοιχα.

Στη συνέχεια, ας αποδείξουμε την Ιδιότητα 8. Εάν η συνάρτηση $f(x,y)$ είναι πραγματική, γνωρίζουμε από την Ιδιότητα 3, πως το πραγματικό μέρος του μετασχηματισμού $F(u,\upsilon)$ είναι άρτιο; επομένως, προκειμένου να αποδείξουμε την Ιδιότητα 8, όλα όσα έχουμε να κάνουμε είναι να αποδείξουμε πως εάν η συνάρτηση $f(x,y)$ είναι πραγματική \emph {και} άρτια, τότε, το φανταστικό μέλος της $F(u,\upsilon)$ είναι ίσο με το μηδέν (δηλαδή, πως η συνάρτηση $F$ είναι πραγματική). Για να το κάνουμε αυτό ξεκινούμε από την εξίσωση
\begin{equation*}
F(u,\upsilon)=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}f(x,y)e^{-j2\pi(ux/M+\upsilon y/N)}
\end{equation*}
το οποίο διαδοχικά μετασχηματίζεται ως
\begin{align*}
F(u,\upsilon)&=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}[f_r(x,y)]\:e^{-j2\pi(ux/M+\upsilon y/N)}=
\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}[f_r(x,y)]\:e^{-j2\pi(ux/M)}e^{-j2\pi(\upsilon y/N)}\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}[\mbox{άρτιο}][\mbox{άρτιο}-j\cdot\mbox{περιττό}][\mbox{άρτιο}-j\cdot\mbox{περιττό}]\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}[\mbox{άρτιο}][\mbox{άρτιο}\cdot\mbox{άρτιο}-2j\cdot
\mbox{άρτιο}\cdot\mbox{περιττό}-\mbox{περιττό}\cdot\mbox{περιττό}]\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}[\mbox{άρτιο}\cdot\mbox{άρτιο}]-2j\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}
\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}[\mbox{άρτιο}\cdot\mbox{περιττό}]-\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}[\mbox{άρτιο}\cdot\mbox{άρτιο}]=
\mbox{πραγματική συνάρτηση}
\end{align*}
Στην παραπάνω παραγωγή, το τέταρτο βήμα προέκυψε από τον τύπο του \textlatin{Euler} και το γεγονός πως οι συναρτήσεις του συνημιτόνου και του ημιτόνου χαρακτηρίζονται από άρτια και περιττή συμμετρία αντίστοιχα. Γνωρίζουμε επίσης από την Ιδιότητα 8, πως η συνάρτηση $f$, θα πρέπει εκτός από το να είναι πραγματική, να χαρακτηρίζεται και από άρτια συμμετρία. Ο μόνος όρος στην προτελευταία γραμμή που περιέχει φανταστικές συνιστώσες είναι ο δεύτερος όρος, ο οποίος σύμφωνα με την Εξίσωση (4.6-14), είναι ίσος με το μηδέν. Επομένως, εάν η συνάρτηση $f$ είναι πραγματική και άρτια, τότε ο μετασχηματισμός $F$ είναι πραγματικός. Όπως επισημάναμε προηγουμένως, ο $F$ είναι επίσης άρτιος, αφού η $f$ είναι πραγματική, κάτι που ολοκληρώνει την απόδειξη.

Ας αποδείξουμε τέλος την ισχύ της Ιδιότητας 6. Από τον ορισμό του διακριτού μετασχηματισμού \textlatin{Fourier}$^{24}$\footnotetext[24]{Ας σημειωθεί πως στην προκειμένη περίπτωση δεν προχωρούμε σε αλλαγή μεταβλητής; το μόνο που κάνουμε είναι να υπολογίσουμε το διακριτό μετασχηματισμό \textlatin{Fourier} της συνάρτησης $f(-x,-y)$ και για το λόγο αυτό, απλά αντικαθιστούμε αυτή τη συνάρτηση στην εξίσωση ορισμού του, όπως θα κάναμε και με οποιαδήποτε άλλη συνάρτηση.}
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}\{f(-x,-y)\}=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}f(-x,-y)e^{-j2\pi(ux/M+\upsilon y/N)}
\end{equation*}
Εξαιτίας της περιοδικότητας της συνάρτησης $f(x,y)$ θα είναι $f(-x,-y)=f(M-x,N-y)$. Ορίζοντας τώρα τις μεταβλητές $m=M-x$ και $n=N-y$ θα λάβουμε
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}\{f(-x,-y)\}=\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f(m,n)e^{-j2\pi(u[M-m]/M+\upsilon[N-n]/N)}
\end{equation*}
(προκειμένου να πειστείτε πως τα παραπάνω αθροίσματα είναι σωστά, ξεκινήστε από ένα μονοδιάστατο μετασχηματισμό και αναπτύξτε κάποιους όρους με το χέρι). Επειδή όμως γνωρίζουμε ότι $\exp[-j2\pi\cdot\mbox{(έναν ακέραιο)}]=1$ η παραπάνω σχέση θα λάβει τη μορφή
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}\{f(-x,-y)\}=\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f(m,n)e^{-j2\pi(um/M+\upsilon n/N)}=F(-u,-\upsilon)
\end{equation*}
σχέση, που ολοκληρώνει την απόδειξη.

\end{example2}
\end{document}
```

An example of the situation is shown below ... a page break is entered for some reason but i dont know why ... sometimes this happens, sometimes not ..

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to float?

Comment: no I just want to print it correctly in a fixed position .. is there something in the definition that allows the environment to float? maybe this is the problem

Comment: No, I do not get the exact problem with spacing you are talking about. Could you maybe insert a screenshot to show us which space is the problem?

Comment: sure, i just added a screenshot in my question .. thanks for your interest

Comment: You could intelligently insert paragraphs (blank line in source code) and that will help you out here. One good example for this is to add a paragraph before `\begin{equation*}` in line 59.